# Managing duplicate keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I want to make a user-level method inside a class, in which arguments can be passed through several variation of a keyword.
To do so, I set up a list of allowed variations for each keyword argument and check for each keyword in each of these lists. e.g. :

```
def some_function(self, **kwargs):
    """
    this function does something with a and b as keyword args
    """
    dict_allowed_a = ['a_variation1','a_variation2',...]
    dict_allowed_b = ['b_variation1','b_variation2',...]

    for arg_str in kwargs():
        if arg_str in dict_allowed_a:
            local_a = kwargs[arg_str]
        if arg_str in dict_allowed_b:
            local_b = kwargs[arg_str]
        else:
            print('Invalid keyword', file=sys.stderr)
            raise ValueError

return self._private_method(local_a, local_b)
```

I have 3 questions, from more specific to less specific :

1. How can I check if someone passed several variations of one
   argument, which has to raise an exception.
2. Am I doing this properly ?
3. Should I even do this, trying to manage variable inputs ?

Comment: 1. You'll know that if e.g. `local_a` is already set. 2. You aren't currently doing that at all. 3. It doesn't seem like a *great* idea, but we don't know your goals and constraints.

Comment: `avariations = [k for k in kwargs.keys() if k.startswith('avariation')]`

Comment: second `if` should be `elif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that you have to deal with strange situations, such as

1. The user specify both `a_variation1` and `a_variation2`
2. The user does not specify any of them

I would use something like

```
local_a = ([kwargs[x] for x in kwargs.keys() if x in dict_allowed_a] + [None])[0]
local_b = ([kwargs[x] for x in kwargs.keys() if x in dict_allowed_b] + [None])[0]
```

Please notice that `[0]` will extract the first value only, this handles case 1.

`[None]` is something like a default, it's used in case 2.